# Getting the value of included jsp in js

Tags: javascript, include

```
I'm using struts 2 application where 
< s: form name="myForm">
< s:include value = "test.jsp" >< / s:include>
< img src="../../images/next.png" onclick="fnNext();"/>
< / s:form>

test.jsp contains a table with id = "my table"
```

Now how use the id of the table in javascript function fnNext():

Comment: Same way as any other DOM element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `element = document.getElementById(id)` or using Jquery to select it using `$('#your_id')`

Answer (score 0):

If you view the source of the resulting `JSP`, you can see that `include` tag includes the output of a `test.jsp` in your original `JSP`.

So you can simply get the table like any other DOM element, in your js file:

```
table = document.getElementById(idOfYourTable);
```

Hope this helps!